# Conditional load Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, systemjs

I need make redirect to login page, before load Angular2 application(without loading it).
My project is based on angular2-quicksart

When I load angular2 js file after uglifyjs

```
<script>
    var cookie = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    if (cookie == undefined){
        window.location.href = LOGIN_SERVER_URL
    } else {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "build/app/bundle.min.js";
        head.appendChild(script);
        head.innerHTML += ("<script>System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); }); <\/script>");
    }
</script>
```

This solution works. JS was loaded and application is running.

When I use systemjs file to load Angular app, systemjs.config.js was loaded, but app doesn't run.

`script.src = "systemjs.config.js";

Can I load systemjs dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should load System JS ..

https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/index.html

This is taken from the Angular Quickstart project.

I'm providing the entire index.html for context:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

SystemJS is loaded up front, not dynamically. The job of System JS is a dynamic module loader but, since you don't have a module loader until System JS is loaded, you cannot load System JS itself dynamically.